# Should I configure BIND nameserver using a static ip

Tags: static, dns, ip, configure

I am trying to setup my own dns server, using bind on centos 6.5. Because I do not know much about it, I am working an several tutorials found in google.

All the tutorials use an internal ip, like 192.168.1.98 etc, however, it might sound silly, but I cannot find an internal ip on my VPS. So my question is this: should I configure bind using my static ip?

More Information:
I have read many tutorials on how to find the internal ip, but unfortunately everywhere appears my static ip.
I know I have understood something wrong, but cannot configure what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There no point binding a nameserver to an interface with an RFC1918 address if that's done on a remote machine, which can't be reached by that address over the net. I assume your VPS *is* remote. You ought to ask yourself "Who is supposed to be able to query my name server". If the answer includes anybody not sitting at a machine connected to the local network your VPS is on, then yes, you need to bind it to the public address.  Which raises the question, about "should I configure bind using my static ip?": what configuration do you refer to? Because most likely your nameserver will bind itself already to all interfaces it can find, rendering the need to tell where to bind it to unnecessary. So you may refer to some part of configuration you have chosen to not disclose what part that might be.